# clEnqueueNDRangeKernel return CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE

Tags: opencl

I have 3 OpenCL devices on my MacBookPro, so I am trying a little bit complicated calculation with a small exsample.

I create a context contain 3 devices, two are GPU and one is CPU.  Then create 3 command queues, one from(or for) each of them.

Then create a big global buffer, big but not bigger than the smallest one available in any one of the device.  Then create 3 sub buffers from the input buffer, the sizes of them are all calculated carefully.  Another not so big output buffer is also created and 3 small sub buffers created on it.

After setup the kernel, set arguments and so on, everything looks good.  The first two device accept the kernel and start to run, but the third one refused it and return CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE.

I don't want to put any source code here as their are nothing special and I am sure there is no bug in it.

I did some log as the following:

```
command queue 0
device: Iris Pro max work group size 512
local work size(32 * 16) = 512
global work size(160 * 48) = 7680
number of work groups = 15

command queue 1 
device: GeForce GT 750M max work group size 1024
local work size(32 * 32) = 1024
global work size(160 * 96) = 15360
number of work groups = 15

command queue 2 
device: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4850HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz max work group size 1024
local work size(32 * 32) = 1024
global work size(160 * 96) = 15360
number of work groups = 15
```

I checked the first two output are correct as expected, so the kernel and host code must be correct.
There is only one possibility I can think of, is there any limit when using CPU and GPU at the same time and share one buffer object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figure out the problem.  The CPU support max work item size (1024, 1, 1), so local work size cannot use (32x32).

But still have problem when use local work size bigger than (1, 1).  Keep trying.

Comment: In addition to the global maximum, each kernel may have it's own maximum local work group size. Use the lGetKernelWorkGroupInfo to get it. I've heard if you use barriers, the CPU device will have a max of 1,1,1.

Comment: I tested with another AMD CPU(quite old) with AMDAPPSDK, it support 1024 work group size, but work item size is (1024, 1024, 10240).  It accept the kernel (32x32).   Maybe the Intel CPU has extra limit, will test again.

Answer (score 0):

From Intel's OpenCL guide:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/540486

Query CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE return always 1, even with a very simple kernel without barrier.  In that case, work group size can be 128 (it's a 1D work group), but cannot be 256.

Conclusion is better not use it in some case :(

Comment: CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE is unrelated to this discusssion. Look at clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo with CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE.

Comment: That give a hint, why it fails.  Maybe only Intel engineer can tell what happened.